# How to reset PEAR configuration to default values?

Tags: macos, mamp, pear

I am having some PEAR issues which I assume to be PEAR/MAMP configuration related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482265/mamp-pear-configuration-is-pointing-to-local-directories

Therefore I would like to reset the PEAR configuration to default values.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some digging, the solution is the following:

check where your configuration files are located:

```
pear config-show
```

in my case:

- User Configuration File: /Users/udos/.pearrc
- System Configuration File: /private/etc/pear.conf

**note:**
you can edit PEAR configuration with command

```
pear config-set [options] <parameter> <value> [layer]
```

the interesting part is [layer]. the default is **user** which affects

- User Configuration File: /Users/udos/.pearrc

alternatively you can use **system** which affects

- System Configuration File: /private/etc/pear.conf

to reset PEAR configuration you have to delete both configuration files.